# TypeError: res.json is not a function (not able to get fetch data)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, express

I m trying to GET response using fetch API not stuck in a error as I mentioned below. Here's my code

```
const DefaultLayout = () => {
      let history = useHistory()
      const callHomePage = async () => {
        try {
          const res = fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/authenticate', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            credentials: 'include',
          })
          console.log(res)
          const data = await res.json()
          console.log(data)
          if (!res.status === 200) {
            const error = new Error(res.error)
            throw error
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
          history.push('login')
        }
    }
```

**Error:** TypeError: res.json is not a function
*Promise* **{}** shows pending

Comment: You  need the `await` in `const res = await fetch(...)`

Answer (score 2):

```
const DefaultLayout = () => {
  let history = useHistory()
  const callHomePage = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/authenticate', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: 'include',
      })
      console.log(res)
      const data = await res.json()
      console.log(data)
      if (!res.status === 200) {
        const error = new Error(res.error)
        throw error
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      history.push('login')
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is no need to await `res.json` since its not a promise.

Comment: res.json() is a method which will returns a promise. So, you have to await for the JSON data.

Comment: Oh ok. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` the fetch statement and then call the `.json` method of the response.

```js
const res = await fetch(...)

data = await res.json();
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: `data = await res.json()` would be needed.   See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json.